# What is the best way on python 2.3 for windows to execute a program like ghostscript with multiple arguments and spaces in paths?

Tags: python, windows, ghostscript

Surely there is some kind of abstraction that allows for this?

This is essentially the command

```
cmd = self._ghostscriptPath + 'gswin32c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiffg4 
      -r196X204 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile="' + tifDest + " " + pdfSource + '"'

os.popen(cmd)
```

this way looks really dirty to me, there must be some pythonic way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess), it superseeds os.popen, though it is not much more of an abstraction:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

#this is how I'd mangle the arguments together
output = Popen([
    self._ghostscriptPath, 
   'gswin32c',
   '-q',
   '-dNOPAUSE',
   '-dBATCH',
   '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
   '-r196X204',
   '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
   '-sOutputFile="%s %s"' % (tifDest, pdfSource),
], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

If you have only python 2.3 which has no subprocess module, you can still use os.popen

```
os.popen(' '.join([
    self._ghostscriptPath, 
   'gswin32c',
   '-q',
   '-dNOPAUSE',
   '-dBATCH',
   '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
   '-r196X204',
   '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
   '-sOutputFile="%s %s"' % (tifDest, pdfSource),
]))
```