# display pdf pages with GUI on tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pypdf

I`m using pyPdf to crop pdf pages. 
And the only thing i miss, is GUI for this script.
I picked up tkinter  module to do the GUI, but i cannot find whether it is possible to display pdf pages with GUI created with tkinter.

Any thoughts ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter has no support for displaying pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I once tried doing the same thing, and I managed to do it in wxPython with a widget that does just that. On Qt however, I didn't manage to do such a thing, and I doubt you could with Tkinter too.

The closest I got was converting to images and displaying the images: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002055/converting-pdf-to-images-automatically).

**Note:** I'm talking about wxPython and Qt, but I guess the same principle applies for Tkinter.