# How to convert a PDF to image format (jpeg, png,...) using my C program?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I'm working with Visual Studio and OpenCV for image processing, but all my documents are PDF so I need to convert them to image format so I can compatibilize them with OpenCV

This is my code to open a image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNFg1.png)

Is there any way to modify it to open and read PDF's as an image?

Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002055/converting-pdf-to-images-automatically - are your PDFs images or text?

Comment: Sorry, I have explained the problem wrong, I'll edit it

Comment: Pleas don't post images of text, or links to images of text. Post the text.

Comment: Please don't tag a question as C if you're using C++. They're different languages.

Comment: Also, please don't use the [visual-studio] tag unless you have a question about the tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at ImageMagick. The CLI tool is able to convert PDF to images and I believe they provide C libraries too.

Comment: Yes I tried, I have downloaded the program but I don't know how to insert the files in Visual Studio and what code I do have to write