# Python, trying to run a program from the command prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-prompt, os.system

I am trying to run a program from the command prompt in windows. I am having some issues. The code is below:

```
commandString = "'C:\Program Files\WebShot\webshotcmd.exe' //url '" + columns[3] + "' //out '"+columns[1]+"~"+columns[2]+".jpg'"
os.system(commandString)
time.sleep(10)
```

So with the single quotes I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." If I replace the single quotes with \" then it says something to the effect of "'C:\Program' is not a valid executable."

I realize it is a syntax error, but I am not quite sure how to fix this....

column[3] contains a full url copy pasted from a web browser (so it should be url encoded). column[1] will only contain numbers and periods. column[2] contains some text, double quotes and colons are replaced. Mentioning just in case...

Thanks!

Comment: try removing the single quotes.

Comment: Also, read all of these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subprocess+windows.  Your question is a duplicate.  For example, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221097/what-is-the-best-way-on-python-2-3-for-windows-to-execute-a-program-like-ghostscr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module for calling system commands. Also ,try removing the single quotes and use double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

- Windows requires double quotes in this situation, and you used single quotes.
- Use the `subprocess` module rather than `os.system`, which is more robust and avoids calling the shell directly, making you not have to worry about confusing escaping issues.
- Dont use `+` to put together long strings. Use string formatting (`string %s" % (formatting,)`), which is more readable, efficient, and idiomatic.
- In this case, don't form a long string as a shell command anyhow, make a list and pass it to `subprocess.call`.
- As best as I can tell you are escaping your forward slash but not your backslashes, which is backwards. A string literal with `//` has both slashes in the string it makes. In any event, rather than either you should use the `os.path` module which avoids any confusion from parsing escapes and often makes scripts more portable.